# How do I fix the Code Page in SSIS Lookup Transformation to be 65001?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, collation, sql-server-2019, unicode

I have an SQL server 2019 with databases and tables all set with the collation  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_**UTF8**.

The relevant table has `code` and `desc` columns which are both of data type **varchar**.

In SSIS project I have a single Data Flow component:

I have a UTF-8 CSV file read with flat file connection, text column `code` to match is `DT_STR, 65001`

I have a Lookup that is set to "Full Cache" and loads the Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_**UTF8** table, but SSIS thinks the **varchar** columns are `DT_STR, 1252`

Finally the `code` in both CSV and lookup are matched and `desc` is sent to destination table which is on the same Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 collation. The destination component is set to `AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage True` and `DefaultCodePage 65001`.

I now get an error saying the column has more than one code page and cannot run the package.

If not for the mislabeled 1252, this package should run. I believe its something to do with `ExternalMetadataXml`, which is read-only and says all my lookup varchar columns are `CodePage="1252"`.

If I manually edit the package .dtsx with npp and replace all instances of 1252 with 65001, the package can run and seems to do what I expected, as long as I never touch the lookup component again.. That seems a bit messed up of a solution tho, I am hoping there's someone else who has a cleaner way to fix this. Thanks.

edit 2021/03/10: I thought I should clarify, the lookup is using OLE to read a table from the SQL server, and is trying to match `code` column onto the `code` column read from the flat file. The problem is **not** the flat file, which is already recognised as `DT_STR, 65001`. The problem is the Lookup widget reading from a table that should be 65001, somehow ends up with 1252. If I didn't use OLE, and instead read from a UTF8 flat file to create the Lookup widget, there is no error.

Comment: Hi there. **1)** Which column, exactly, is getting the "column has more than one code page" error? **2)** have you tried setting `AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage` to `False`? **3)** In the "Flat File Connection Manager Editor (General Page)", is the file set to code page 65001 or Unicode (should be 65001)? **4)** are both columns in the Lookup Component configured as `DT_STR, 65001`? And, **5)** is your CSV file using a BOM (i.e. does Notepad++ show in the bottom, right "UTF-8", "ANSI", or "UTF-8-BOM")? If not "UTF-8-BOM", trying converting file to "UTF-8-BOM" (_might_ influence external metadata).

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for adding clarification to the question. More questions: **1)** where exactly does 1252 show up in the .dtsx file? Is it in the ConnectionManager used by the Lookup Component? **2)** You say that "The destination component is set to AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage True and DefaultCodePage 65001" but what about the source properties? **3)** For either source or destination connection properties, do either have "Unicode" set to 1 / checked? **4)** You mention that the lookup is using "Full" cache. Have you tried using "No Cache"?

Answer (score 2):

With the disclaimer that I'm a "dumb American" who doesn't deal with non-English data but did work with a friend recently on using bulk import with UTF-8 data, here's what I see.

I have a pipe separated value file that looks like this

```
level|name
7|"Ovasino Poste de Santé"
```

Notepad++ indicates I have saved it as UTF-8.

I created two flat file connection managers in SSIS: Codepage65001STR and Codepage65001WSTR. They both use a Code Page of 65001 (UTF-8)

[image]

In the advanced tab for the STR variant, I left the data type as DT_STR
[image]

In the advanced tab for WSTR variant, I changed the data type to DT_WSTR

[image]

I also created a table and loaded it with the same data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.dba_286478;
CREATE TABLE dbo.dba_286478
(
level int NOT NULL
,   name varchar(75) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8
)
INSERT INTO dbo.dba_286478
(
    level
,   name
)
VALUES
(
    7 -- level - int
,   'Ovasino Poste de Santé' -- name - varchar(75)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.dba_286478;
CREATE TABLE dbo.dba_286478
(
    level int NOT NULL
,   name varchar(75) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8
);
```

I then created a data flow task with a Flat File Source using the different Flat File Connection Managers and added data viewers between them and an empty derived column (so I had an anchor point for the data viewer).

I did the same thing with an OLE DB Source pointing at my table as well as a custom query of

```
SELECT
    T.level
,   CAST(T.name AS varchar(75)) AS name
FROM 
    dbo.dba_286478 AS T;
```

as well as explicitly defining the collation as it makes no different in SSIS

```
,   CAST(T.name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 AS varchar(75)) AS name
```

The results all show the same, the final word is an accented Sante. If the UTF-8 hadn't happened, it'd show as `SantÃ©`

[image]

At this point, it doesn't matter whether we DT_STR or DT_WSTR in our flat file source column definition, the component understands UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Properties, metadata of each. The Codepage 65001 STR looks as expected. code page of 65001 and data type DT_STR

[image]

Unicode, DT_WSTR looks good

[image]

The OLE components however, they're a different animal. The component is returning a metadata of DT_WSTR (full Unicode/UTF-16) regardless of whether we do an explicit cast to DT_STR, optionally specifying collation, or let the natural metadata flow through.

Either way, it doesn't detect the code page/collation stuff and just says Nope, you're Unicode

[image]

So, when we get to trying to use a Lookup task with an OLE DB connection manager, we can expect and receive the same inability to delineate between UTF-8 string/varchar and UTF-16/nvarchar

[image]

The error would indicate and that's true, DT_STR can't match DT_WSTR

> Cannot map the input column, 'name', to the lookup column, 'name', because the data types do not match.

### So what do I do?

You must have type alignment to make the lookup component work which means the source data needs to be of type `DT_WSTR`. You can either bring the data in from the Flat File as Unicode or leave it as string with code page 65001. If you go the latter route, then you need to make a copy, Derived Column or Data Conversion work, of that column and use it in the Lookup component.

If you're pulling text out of the lookup component, that's now in your pipeline as Unicode so you *probably* want to then convert that to a string type with code page. Again, Derived Column or Data Conversion will be used.

[image]

### SSIS OLE components don't understand UTF8

We saw with the source and lookup component that SSIS is going to treat the UTF-8 strings as UTF-16 but I assumed it would handle storing to the table just fine. Not so much.

My server collation is `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` and while I switched accent sensitivities between server and table definition of `dbo.dba_286478`, it doesn't matter in this case as it's UTF-8 all the way down.

For my Flat File Source, I use the STR based file which has the metadata shown above with the yellow highlighting. The Codepage 65001 for data type DT_STR is what we want.

I added an OLE DB Destination and pointed it at my table which again has the "name" column defined as UTF-8

```
name varchar(75) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8
```

Check this error!

[image]

> Validation error. Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [138]: The column "name" cannot be processed because more than one code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it.

We **only** have code page 65001 at play in this data flow and yet, *something* in SSIS space is inferring/defaulting to a 1252 code page during validation.

## Making it work

The componentry in a data flow task was built with OLE DB connections in mind. That's why the Lookup task supported OLE DB Connections for 2005, 2008 and maybe 2008R2? Long time ago now, I know but the Cache Connection Manager (aka anything else) option was added in later iterations because of the need to use something besides OLE connection managers especially given the push then was to deprecate the OLE driver.

An ADO.NET Connection Manager does slightly better than OLE in this case and that's likely what you're going to have to use to work with UTF8 data in an SSIS package. It will be implicitly converting to UTF-16 when it presents to the table and then SQL Server is going to snap it back into UTF-8 space (best I can tell).

For reference, bringing UTF-8 data into the pipeline with ADO Source will still be flagged as DT_WSTR/UTF-16/unicode.

[image]

But you *can* land DT_STR code page 65001 to an ADO.NET Destination without a code page mismatch error like I'm seeing for OLE DB Destination.

[image]

The data from the database is going to appear as DT_WSTR regardless of how you bring it into the pipeline. That means you can define and OLE and an ADO connection manager to use the Lookup component as is.

Or you can add a precursor data flow step to populate the Cache Connection Manager and only have an ADO.NET connection manager. Were you to go that route, convert the DT_WSTR data to DT_STR with codepage 65001 and store that data into the cache.

```
DFT - Populate Cache -> DFT - Load data
```

DFT - Populate Cache

```
ADO.NET Source -> Data Conversion -> Cache Connection Manager
```

DFT - Load Data

```
Flat File Source -> Lookup Component -> ADO.NET Destination
```

Answer (score 2):

I found these tidbits of information while reading through the collation documentation:

> For example, for the **OS locale "English (United States)" (code page 1252)**, the default collation during setup is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, and it can be changed to its **closest Windows collation** counterpart, **Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC**.

<sup>***Reference:** [Collation and Unicode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

...So the collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC does relate to the Windows code page 1252...

> SQL Server 2012 (11.x) introduced a new family of **supplementary character (_SC)** collations that can be used with the **nchar**, **nvarchar**, and **sql_variant** data types to represent the full Unicode character range (000000–10FFFF). For example: **Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC** or, if you're using a Japanese collation, Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CI_AS_SC.

<sup>***Reference:** [Collation and Unicode support - Supplementary characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

... now I know where the _SC comes from and reading on ...

> **SQL Server 2019 (15.x) introduces full support for the widely used UTF-8 character encoding as an import or export encoding, and as database-level or column-level collation for string data.** **UTF-8 is allowed** in the **char** and **varchar** data types, and it's enabled when you create or change an object's collation to a collation that has a UTF8 suffix. One example is changing LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC to **LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8**.

<sup>***Reference:** [Collation and Unicode support - UTF-8 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

... and now we have a matching collation: **LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8**.

Along the line it all sums up to the Windows code page being 1252 and the SQL Server collation being UTF-8.

## Your Fix

Hacking the SSIS package seems to fix the wrong interpretation of the flat file, but only until the package is edited/modified again.

Could it be that the TXT file isn't being interpreted as 100% UTF-8?

## TXT files and UTF-8

I saved the first couple of lines of this answer into a .txt file and had a look at the contents in a Hex-Editor:

#### Hex of Notepad UTF-8

```
00000000h: 49 20 66 6F 75 6E 64 20 74 68 65 73 65 20 74 69 ; I found these ti
00000010h: 64 62 69 74 73 20 6F 66 20 69 6E 66 6F 72 6D 61 ; dbits of informa
00000020h: 74 69 6F 6E 20 77 68 69 6C 65 20 72 65 61 64 69 ; tion while readi
```

There doesn't seem to be a UTF-8 BOM header there.

#### Hex of Notepad ANSI

```
00000000h: 49 20 66 6F 75 6E 64 20 74 68 65 73 65 20 74 69 ; I found these ti
00000010h: 64 62 69 74 73 20 6F 66 20 69 6E 66 6F 72 6D 61 ; dbits of informa
00000020h: 74 69 6F 6E 20 77 68 69 6C 65 20 72 65 61 64 69 ; tion while readi
```

So both ANSI and UTF-8 are stored the same way when using Windows NOTEPAD.EXE.

I do know that a UTF-8 file sometimes comes with a BOM (Byte Order Mark), that specifically denotes the file as UTF-8.

This looks like this:

```
00000000h: EF BB BF 49 20 66 6F 75 6E 64 20 74 68 65 73 65 ; ï»¿I found these
00000010h: 20 74 69 64 62 69 74 73 20 6F 66 20 69 6E 66 6F ;  tidbits of info
00000020h: 72 6D 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 77 68 69 6C 65 20 72 65 ; rmation while re
00000030h: 61 64 69                                        ; adi
```

This basically shouts: **In case you don't know, I am a UTF-8 encoded file...**

But ...

> The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes at the start of a text stream (0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF) that allows the reader to more reliably guess a file as being encoded in UTF-8.
> [...]
> Normally, the BOM is used to signal the endianness of an encoding, but since endianness is irrelevant to UTF-8, the BOM is unnecessary.

<sup>***Reference:** [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Wikipedia)*</sup>

## Possible Conclusion

Going back on the quoted information in the introduction...

> ...SQL Server 2019 (15.x) introduces **full support for the widely used UTF-8 character encoding** as an import or export encoding, and as database-level or column-level collation for string data. UTF-8 is allowed ....

What is the definition of **full support for the widely used UTF-8 character encoding**? With or without BOM? We don't know so let's try another approach.

## Possible Solution

**I suggest you grab a tool that supports saving TXT files as UTF-8 and which will insert the BOM.**

This way you ensure that the SSIS package will interpret the TXT file correctly as UTF-8 and will not convert the package to interpret Code-page 1252. This way you shouldn't encounter any issues with your SSIS package.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, the flat file is read as UTF8, with the correct 65001 code page. issue is with the OLE lookup, SSIS thinks the server is providing 1252 when the column on server is VARCHAR UTF8 collation. Inspecting the column code page on SQL yields 65001

Comment: Could you provide details in your question on how you verified that the file is being read as UTF-8? Again if the server is located in the United States then the locale is determined to be codepage 1252. If the file does not contain the BOM then it will be "tried" to be read as UTF-8. It can however still be deemed to be codepage 1252. Did you try saving your file as **UTF-8 with BOM**? Did you open the file and look at the first couple of bytes? SSIS and UTF-8 are pretty new paired with the new **_SC_UTF8** collations. You might be hitting a built-in limitation/bug.

Comment: SSIS lets you specify UTF8 65001 as the code page, see the first image of billinkc's answer

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that fact.

Comment: Hello @softwarenewbie7332 and John: Just FYI, the statement, "_Along the line it all sums up to the Windows code page being 1252 and the SQL Server collation being UTF-8._", is incorrect. This is a Windows collation, not a SQL Server collation (as that would have a name starting with `SQL_`). Also, it's impossible to be both code page 1252 _and_ UTF-8 at the same time. Both are 8-bit encodings, and UTF-8 is code page 65001, and you can only have 1 code page as that is _the_ encoding for that column or expression. The collation specified by the O.P. is correct and doesn't imply code page 1252.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7332 and John: Also, the statement (in a comment above) about, "_if the server is located in the United States then the locale is determined to be codepage 1252._" is incorrect. The location of a computer is irrelevant. Now, the language/locale setting of the OS _is_ used to suggest the default server collation when installing SQL Server, and if the OS is using English/US then it will suggest a collation tied to code page 1252. BUT, a file will be interpreted as being the code page specified by whatever is reading the file, in this case the Flat File Connection Manager.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky ok slightly wrong wording on my behalf. I am aware of codepage and collation being totally different things. However the codepage (OS) can be different than the collation (SQL Server). And yes a **Windows SQL Server Collation** will be missing the ' SQL_'  part. I never wrote otherwise in my sentence: "Along the line...". My intention is to have the BOM in the UTF-8 file to see if the SSIS (exe) will then interpret the file correctly as UTF-8 which will allow OP to leave the package as is.

Comment: Hi John. I'm just saying that the terminology is being used incorrectly here, or at least in a potentially misleading/confusing way. Code page is a valid term for both the OS locale and the collation used within SQL Server; there's no reason to use "code page" exclusively with the OS. And the documentation you quoted is for the installer (i.e. for US English OSs, it will suggest using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`), not in general. In fact, the OEM code page is typically 437 for US English OSs. And, there is no "Windows SQL Server Collation". It either a "Windows" or a "SQL Server" collation.